# Git with Cpanel - can't push

Tags: git, cpanel

Hi all and thanks in advance for viewing this and for trying to help.

I am trying to use git with cpanel on (namecheap) shared servers through SSH.
While I am able to clone / pull (if I upload files and commit them), it does not allow me to push from local to remote repo.

I am having the following error:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

I tried creating a new branch locally to not push master to remote master as explained in some answers here, on SO. Also tried to `git init --bare`, doesn't seem to work either.

Any help is much appreciated as I lost the last 5 hours trying to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Git typically has two kinds of repositories, those which include a working space, and those which lack a working space.  The latter is a "bare" repository, and while it tracks files, merges, branches, and other items, it is not used as the recipient of a code checkout, not used as a place to edit files, and not used as a place to push files to a remote.

It seems that the git repository you are working on is a non-bare repository, and you are attempting to update from a remote.  If that was the situation, your local branch of "master" already has a history.  You would need to merge the remote history into yours.